# Wrapping COM objects with IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, rubberduck, wrapper, com

One of the things believed to contribute to destabilizing Rubberduck 2.x, is the fact that a lot of COM object references are stored in many places, and `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` is never called for those, which is what the alleged problem would be.

To fix this, I've undertaken the task of completely wrapping the VBIDE API with managed types that implement `IDisposable` and call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` when disposing.

This presented several problems:

- The wrapped object reference might be `null`; but wrapping a `null` reference means things like `if (wrapper == null)` wouldn't behave properly; hence, the wrappers should override `==` and `!=` operators to make null-checks work more intuitively.
- The COM threading model (STA) isn't completely compatible with .NET's (MTA); although *in theory* all managed calls get marshaled into a STA call, in practice the managed RCW could be "disconnected" from the underlying COM object, which basically means literally *anything* can throw a `COMException` - including a simple getter read. Wrapping everything in `try/catch` blocks would make for excessively redundant code, hence a generic invocation mechanism was implemented, to invoke a COM object's member while catching a `COMException`.
- Because the managed code implements `IDisposable`, we'll want an `ObjectDisposedException` to be thrown whenever a member is accessed on a disposed object. Hence, a general-purpose "throw if disposed" mechanism was implemented, to simplify the implementations.

Here is the base class from which all wrappers will be derived:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Rubberduck.VBEditor.DisposableWrappers
{
    public abstract class WrapperBase<T> : IDisposable
        where T : class 
    {
        private readonly T _item;
        private bool _isDisposed;

        protected WrapperBase(T item)
        {
            _item = item;
        }

        protected internal T Item
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed(_isDisposed);
                return _item;
            }
        }

        public bool IsNull
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed(_isDisposed);
                return _item == null;
            }
        }

        public static bool operator ==(WrapperBase<T> object1, WrapperBase<T> object2)
        {
            if (object1 != null && object1.IsNull)
            {
                return (object)object2 == null;
            }
            if (object2 != null && object2.IsNull)
            {
                return (object)object1 == null;
            }

            return ReferenceEquals(object1, object2);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(WrapperBase<T> object1, WrapperBase<T> object2)
        {
            return !(object1 == object2);
        }

        protected static TResult InvokeMemberValue<TResult>(Func<TResult> member)
        {
            try
            {
                return member.Invoke();
            }
            catch (COMException exception)
            {
                throw new WrapperMethodException(exception);
            }
        }

        protected static TResult InvokeMemberValue<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> member, T param)
        {
            try
            {
                return member.Invoke(param);
            }
            catch (COMException exception)
            {
                throw new WrapperMethodException(exception);
            }
        }

        protected static TResult InvokeMemberValue<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<T1, T2, TResult> member, T1 param1, T2 param2)
        {
            try
            {
                return member.Invoke(param1, param2);
            }
            catch (COMException exception)
            {
                throw new WrapperMethodException(exception);
            }
        }

        protected static void InvokeMember(Action member)
        {
            try
            {
                member.Invoke();
            }
            catch (COMException exception)
            {
                throw new WrapperMethodException(exception);
            }
        }

        protected static void InvokeMember<T>(Action<T> member, T param)
        {
            try
            {
                member.Invoke(param);
            }
            catch (COMException exception)
            {
                throw new WrapperMethodException(exception);
            }
        }

        protected static void InvokeMember<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> member, T1 param1, T2 param2)
        {
            try
            {
                member.Invoke(param1, param2);
            }
            catch (COMException exception)
            {
                throw new WrapperMethodException(exception);
            }
        }

        protected static void InvokeMember<T1, T2, T3>(Action<T1, T2, T3> member, T1 param1, T2 param2, T3 param3)
        {
            try
            {
                member.Invoke(param1, param2, param3);
            }
            catch (COMException exception)
            {
                throw new WrapperMethodException(exception);
            }
        }

        protected static void InvokeMember<T1, T2, T3, T4>(Action<T1, T2, T3, T4> member, T1 param1, T2 param2, T3 param3, T4 param4)
        {
            try
            {
                member.Invoke(param1, param2, param3, param4);
            }
            catch (COMException exception)
            {
                throw new WrapperMethodException(exception);
            }
        }

        protected static void ThrowIfDisposed(bool isDisposed)
        {
            if (isDisposed) { throw new ObjectDisposedException("Object has been disposed."); }
        }

        protected void ThrowIfDisposed()
        {
            ThrowIfDisposed(_isDisposed);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_isDisposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_item);
            _isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This base class allows me to wrap the VBIDE API types; here's the wrapper implementation for the `Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Window` interface:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;

namespace Rubberduck.VBEditor.DisposableWrappers
{
    public class Window : WrapperBase<Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Window>, IDisposable
    {
        public Window(Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Window window)
            : base(window)
        {
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            ThrowIfDisposed();
            InvokeMember(() => Item.Close());
        }

        public void SetFocus()
        {
            ThrowIfDisposed();
            InvokeMember(() => Item.SetFocus());
        }

        public void SetKind(WindowKind eKind)
        {
            ThrowIfDisposed();
            InvokeMember(kind => Item.SetKind((vbext_WindowType)kind), eKind);
        }

        public void Detach()
        {
            ThrowIfDisposed();
            InvokeMember(() => Item.Detach());
        }

        public void Attach(int lWindowHandle)
        {
            ThrowIfDisposed();
            InvokeMember(handle => Item.Attach(handle), lWindowHandle);
        }

        public VBE VBE
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed(); 
                return new VBE(InvokeMemberValue(() => Item.VBE));
            }
        }

        public Windows Collection
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed();
                return new Windows(InvokeMemberValue(() => Item.Collection));
            }
        }

        public string Caption
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed(); 
                return InvokeMemberValue(() => Item.Caption);
            }
        }

        public bool Visible
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed(); 
                return InvokeMemberValue(() => Item.Visible);
            }
        }

        public int Left
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed(); 
                return InvokeMemberValue(() => Item.Left);
            }
        }

        public int Top
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed(); 
                return InvokeMemberValue(() => Item.Top);
            }
        }

        public int Width
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed(); 
                return InvokeMemberValue(() => Item.Width);
            }
        }

        public int Height
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed(); 
                return InvokeMemberValue(() => Item.Height);
            }
        }

        public WindowState WindowState
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed();
                return InvokeMemberValue(() => (WindowState)Item.WindowState);
            }
        }

        public WindowKind Type
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed(); 
                return (WindowKind)InvokeMemberValue(() => Item.Type);
            }
        }

        public LinkedWindows LinkedWindows
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed();
                return new LinkedWindows(InvokeMemberValue(() => Item.LinkedWindows));
            }
        }

        public Window LinkedWindowFrame
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed(); 
                return new Window(InvokeMemberValue(() => Item.LinkedWindowFrame));
            }
        }

        public int HWnd
        {
            get
            {
                ThrowIfDisposed(); 
                return InvokeMemberValue(() => Item.HWnd);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice I'm returning new wrapper instances whenever a member needs to return an object - that way I'm avoiding the incestuous object references of the wrapped object tree (pretty much everything in the VBIDE API has a `VBE` property that points to the parent/top-most object); the idea being that calling this member involves a new RCW and a reference counter increment, and therefore needs to be disposed/released as well:

> ```
>     public VBE VBE
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             ThrowIfDisposed(); 
>             return new VBE(InvokeMemberValue(() => Item.VBE));
>         }
>     }
> ```

So I'll be making it the calling code's responsibility to ensure `Dispose` gets called for every `IDisposable` wrapper involved - and contrary to `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`, I'll be getting compiler warnings for not calling `IDisposable.Dispose` when that call doesn't happen.

I'm also wrapping the enum types:

```
/// <summary>
/// Values compatible with <see cref="Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.vbext_WindowType"/> enum values.
/// </summary>
public enum WindowKind
{
    CodeWindow = 0,
    Designer = 1,
    Browser = 2,
    Watch = 3,
    Locals = 4,
    Immediate = 5,
    ProjectWindow = 6,
    PropertyWindow = 7,
    Find = 8,
    FindReplace = 9,
    Toolbox = 10,
    LinkedWindowFrame = 11,
    MainWindow = 12,
    ToolWindow = 15,
}
```

That way I can reuse everything when I need to wrap the VBIDE library for the VB6 IDE - I guess I'm going to need to copy all wrappers, and simply change the namespace in the generic type specification; I'll probably end up with `Rubberduck.VBEditor.DisposableWrappers.VBA` and `Rubberduck.VBEditor.DisposableWrappers.VB6` namespaces, both with very similar types... that don't implement a common interface for their members... I can smell the nightmare coming.

The other implemented wrappers (that's all still WIP) can be found [in my GitHub repository](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/tree/26e8452ac99b639b6b5dbce0c67e2547bfdf2e35/Rubberduck.VBEEditor/DisposableWrappers).

I'd like to receive constructive feedback on this approach before I get too far down the rabbit hole - is this a viable way of wrapping a COM interop library? Does anything look off? Am I falling into some "easy" trap with this implementation?

I specifically avoided implementing the wrapped interfaces, so as to avoid "leaking" any COM objects into my code base (e.g. there'd be a `VBE` property returning a `Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.VBE` COM object, vs here a `VBE` property returning a `Rubberduck.VBEditor.DisposableWrappers.VBE`). That's a good call, right?

Comment: Why would you ever want to call `static void ThrowIfDisposed(bool isDisposed)`, given that _isDisposed is a private member field? And shouldn't you be implementing a finalizer in your base class to ensure the COM resource is cleaned up even if the class gets GC'd without the user calling `Dispose`?

Comment: @eurotrash the base class didn't start off generic; at first I had the wrapped object a private field of the derived type, and at one point I made the base class itself `IDisposable` and moved as much as I could in there - `static void ThrowIfDisposed(bool)` is a remnant of that and could probably be removed. As for the finalizer - you see that's exactly why I'm putting this up for review ;-)

Comment: Even though the namespace is descriptive, `WrapperBase` feels like a poor name for what its purpose is. Maybe `SafeComWrapper`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is two things that caught my attention.

#### Every public method / property of all implementing classes

needs to call `ThrowIfDisposed()`. Always. That's the requirements and what you started here is "manually" invoking that each and every time...

This seems to be quite a lot of work for something that could be accomplished significantly faster with Aspect-Oriented-Programming (an Interceptor or Decorator). I know Rubberduck is already using interceptors for logging ... I wonder whether it's possible to remove this tedious (and somewhat error prone) "manual" checking in favor of an "automated" check.

#### Needless overloads

You're passing an action and it's parameters to `InvokeMember` and `InvokeMemberValue` respectively. I don't understand why ... it should be easy to partially apply all invocations you want at the callsite of `InvokeMember` into an `Action` either way. Since you pass the parameters and an action and you have those available where you call `InvokeMember` why overload that.

Consider changing things like:

> ```
>         InvokeMember(handle => Item.Attach(handle), lWindowHandle);
> ```

into a "cheaper" and partially applied action like this:

```
InvokeMember(() => Item.Attach(lWindowHandle));
```

It should not make a difference for the purpose of where the Exception is thrown and in gets rid of 6 methods in your WrapperBase that you won't need anymore... I think that's quite a benefit.

Comment: You make a good point in the first part; this definitely looks like a job for some (heavily reusable) decorator. Interception would work *if the types were injected*, but that's not the case here, the wrappers are spawned from wrappers.. I think introducing factories would be much overkill, the coupling is ok here IMO. As for the invoke overloads, I'm worried about implicitly capturing a RCW in a closure, in cases where a wrapped member takes a COM type for a parameter. Or am I being paranoid here?

Comment: The setter for [VBE.ActiveVBProject](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/blob/next/Rubberduck.VBEEditor/DisposableWrappers/VBE.cs#L21) makes a good example of what I mean. (link points to current version, where I moved the `ThrowIfDisposed` calls to the base class' `Invoke*` members which I made non-static - this cleanly addresses your first point does it? ;-)

Comment: The RCW refcount is only incremented when the ref comes from the COM side. You're right, the overloads *are* pointless.

Answer (score 4):

Just a flying review:

Have you tested this? The equality code isn't at all right. Firstly, never override `==` and `!=` without overriding the `object.Equals` method. You'll end up with a check that will be different depending on which way you do the test - that's bad.

Secondly, your code can't handle this really easy test:

```
 var item1 = new WrapperBase<string>(null);
 Console.WriteLine(item1 == null);
```

That results in a `StackOverflowException` and this is the wrong site for that!

Your problem is `object1 != null` and `object2 != null` because you've defined `!=` to just be `!(==)` you'll infinitely recurse. Use ReferenceEqual instead:

```
public static bool operator ==(WrapperBase<T> left, WrapperBase<T> right)
{
    if (!ReferenceEquals(left, null) && left.IsNull)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(right, null);
    }
    if (!ReferenceEquals(right, null) && right.IsNull)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(left, null);
    }
    return ReferenceEquals(left, right);
}
```

Comment: Aye, I actually removed these operators, it just felt completely wrong without `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overrides.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I seem to recall Unity do something similar with equality to null... I just can't remember where or why :S

Answer (score 2):

> *The wrapped object reference might be `null`*

Then there's a bug right here:

> ```
> public void Dispose()
> {
>     if (_isDisposed)
>     {
>         return;
>     }
>
>     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_item);
>     _isDisposed = true;
> }
> ```

You need a null check against `_item` before you pass it to `ReleaseComObject`.

---

As mentioned in [Vogel612's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142981/23788), the `ThrowIfDisposed` calls are easy to forget (especially in larger wrappers exposing lots of members).

The `InvokeXxxx` methods don't need to be `static`. By making them instance methods, you can move `ThrowIfDisposed()` calls there:

```
protected void Invoke(Action member)
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    try
    {
        member.Invoke();
    }
    catch (COMException exception)
    {
        throw new WrapperMethodException(exception);
    }
}
```

And now all the derived types need to remember is to `Invoke` everything.

---

The `IDisposable` implementation is a bit bare-bones: if a derived type needs to `.Dispose` its own resources, you're stuck. That's why the [*dispose pattern*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) has this `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)` member. The type also needs a finalizer [as eurotrash mentioned](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142916/wrapping-com-objects-with-idisposable#comment268006_142916), to ensure resources are disposed properly when the object gets finalized before `Dispose` was called.

The parameterized `ThrowIfDisposed(bool)` overload should be removed, too.